# android doesnt realize that progressbar is initialized

Tags: java, android, xml

so i am doing an app with webviews that have a progressbar while it loads and i did this in several activities the thing is in one the activities throws this

```
              E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.examplem16.vics_0.m16, PID: 30491
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
                  at com.examplem16.vics_0.m16.ServiciosActivity$MyWebViewClient.onPageStarted(ServiciosActivity.java:183)
                  at xl.b(SourceFile:219)
                  at agX.handleMessage(SourceFile:20)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

the problem seems to be that when i want to tell the progressbar to turn visible it doesnt recognize it as initialized

i checked an activivity that works and compared it to this one and i dont seem to know whats the problem

here is one activity that works

```
public class CursosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView webView;
private ProgressBar spinner;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cursos);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);



    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_whatsapp_white_48dp);
    fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color
            .parseColor("#4674B7")));
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            try{
                onClickWhatsApp();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
        };
    });


    spinner = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1); //initialize
    spinner.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

    String url = "https://mutual16.org/formacion-profesional/";
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewCursos);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl(url);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient() {


        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            try {
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                        "var head = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0];"
                        + "head.parentNode.removeChild(head);" +
                        "})()");

                webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                        "var head = document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0];"
                        + "head.parentNode.removeChild(head);" +
                        "})()");
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                        "var head = document.getElementsByClassName('ssbp-container')[0];"
                        + "head.parentNode.removeChild(head);" +
                        "})()");
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function getStyle(elem, name) {" +
                        "    // J/S Pro Techniques p136" +
                        "    if (elem.style[name]) {" +
                        "        return elem.style[name];" +
                        "    } else if (elem.currentStyle) {" +
                        "        return elem.currentStyle[name];" +
                        "    }" +
                        "    else if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {" +
                        "        name = name.replace(/([A-Z])/g, \"-$1\");" +
                        "        name = name.toLowerCase();" +
                        "        s = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elem, \"\");" +
                        "        return s && s.getPropertyValue(name);" +
                        "    } else {" +
                        "        return null;" +
                        "    }" + "})()");

                webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {" +
                        "var element = document.getElementById('page-container')," +
                        "padding = getStyle(element, 'paddingTop'); " +
                        "element.style.paddingTop = parseInt(padding, 0) + 0 + 'px';" + "})()");




            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView web, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(web, url);
            spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            setTitle(web.getTitle());

            }


    }
    );
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        String urlHost = Uri.parse(url).getHost();
        switch (urlHost) {
            case "mutual16.org":
                return false;
            case "www.mutual16.org":
                return false;
            case "https://mutual16.org":
                return false;
            default:
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView webview, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(webView, url, favicon);
        spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //same line with problem in the other activity

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        setTitle(view.getTitle());

    }

}

public void onClickWhatsApp() {

    try {
        PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+"543512002828" ;
        i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        if (i.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
            this.startActivity(i);
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}


}
```

and here its its xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".CursosActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_cursos">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme">
    <!-- #4674B7 -->

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/facebookm16blanco2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_logo"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_logo_M16"/>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webViewCursos"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

here is the activity that doesnt work

```
public class ServiciosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView webView;
private ProgressBar spinner;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_servicios);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);



    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_whatsapp_white_48dp);
    fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color
            .parseColor("#4674B7")));
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            try{
                onClickWhatsApp();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
        };
    });


    spinner = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1); //initialize


    String url = "https://mutual16.org/servicios/";
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewServicios);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl(url);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient() {


        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url)
        {
            try {
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                        "var head = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0];"
                        + "head.parentNode.removeChild(head);" +
                        "})()");

                webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                        "var head = document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0];"
                        + "head.parentNode.removeChild(head);" +
                        "})()");
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                        "var head = document.getElementsByClassName('ssbp-container')[0];"
                        + "head.parentNode.removeChild(head);" +
                        "})()");
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function getStyle(elem, name) {" +
                        "    // J/S Pro Techniques p136" +
                        "    if (elem.style[name]) {" +
                        "        return elem.style[name];" +
                        "    } else if (elem.currentStyle) {" +
                        "        return elem.currentStyle[name];" +
                        "    }" +
                        "    else if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {" +
                        "        name = name.replace(/([A-Z])/g, \"-$1\");" +
                        "        name = name.toLowerCase();" +
                        "        s = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elem, \"\");" +
                        "        return s && s.getPropertyValue(name);" +
                        "    } else {" +
                        "        return null;" +
                        "    }" + "})()");

                webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {" +
                                "var element = document.getElementById('page-container')," +
                                "padding = getStyle(element, 'paddingTop'); " +
                                "element.style.paddingTop = parseInt(padding, 0) + 0 + 'px';" +"})()");



            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            setTitle(view.getTitle());

        }


    }
    );
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(webView.canGoBack())
    {
        webView.goBack();
    }
    else
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            String urlHost = Uri.parse(url).getHost();
            switch (urlHost) {
                case "mutual16.org":
                    return false;
                case "www.mutual16.org":
                    return false;
                case "https://mutual16.org":
                    return false;
                default:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
            }
        }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView webview, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(webView, url, favicon);
        spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //line 183

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        setTitle(view.getTitle());

    }

}

public void onClickWhatsApp() {

    try {
        PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+"543512002828" ;
        i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        if (i.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
            this.startActivity(i);
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}






}
```

and here its its xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".ServiciosActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_servicios">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"

    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <!-- #4674B7 -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_logo"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_logo_M16"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/facebookm16blanco2" />


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webViewServicios"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

EDIT:

adding the activity_servicios and activity_cursos xmls as requested by @TheWanderer

first the one that works (activity_cursos)

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".CursosActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_cursos" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

and here the one that doesnt work (activity_servicios)

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ServiciosActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_servicios" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Comment: Why do you have the `tools:showIn` set? Is the XML you posted actually included in another layout?

Comment: that was autogenerated, i suppose that it is because i have an activity and an activity content

Comment: OK. Can you post the `activity_servicios` XML?

Comment: done, added it to the post, i dont think it will help much, i didnt write anything in it

Comment: I noticed all of your XML files are missing closing tags. Did you just not copy them in?

Comment: Yes, i seem to have copied them wrong, but they are actually closed in the files

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any issues in your code. The only other thing I can suggest is to use more unique IDs for all of your Views (not just the ProgressBars) and change your WebViewClient class names as well.

Comment: Hey, can you please clarify if example you posted works or not? It seems to me like your example works. 
According to stackTrace you provided, exception occurred in onPageStarted method. It fires as soon as you start loading a webview. Please check if you initialize *spinner* before web initialization happens.  
Additionally, you should check if *onPageStarted* is fired after default inflation. If so, the only thing you should do is ignore initial call (you may do so by checking if spinner is null).

Comment: @Mladen i clarified in the post itself, i have 2 activities, one of which works (CursosActivity) and what that doesnt (ServiciosActivity) and yes spinner is initialized to be honest i have no idea what the problem is, it most certanly have to be related to the progressbar as the activity was working until i put the progressbar

Answer (score -1):

Finally i was able to pinpoint the reason, i had a layout-v21 folder and content_servicios xml there and didnt have the progressbar there and that was causing the problem, just added the progressbar and it worked